# Which is the _proper_ html element to use for calling action when clicking on an image?

Tags: html, image, action

I have a webapplication where (as in many other ones out there) you click on an image to do something, for instance, mark an entry, send a mail, flag something...

Short, clicking on the image is supposed to call an action (via javascript, but that's not the point).

I was wondering, what is the "right" way to do this?

- `<a>`-tag? Hmm... actually it is not a link...
- `<button>`? Because obviously a button is the semantic element for calling an action...
- `<div>`?

Any hints?

Comment: I'd go for a `<button>`, but it's up to you. I call myself a purist but I haven't wondered about *this* yet :)

Comment: The button is the *semantic* way but doesn't necessarily mean it's the *best* way when you weigh up user expectations and aesthetics. TBH the button element is kind of horrible for both - users are accustomed to clicking on little icons to do stuff. Why break expectations for semantics?

Comment: Seems quite clear to me now, see accepted answer...

(1) if the webapp would be "out in the open": use `<img>` (and add the javascript action via DOM scriping, as we want to be kind to non javascript users).

(2) As my app is inhouse, I will be naughty and go with `<img>`, and directly attach javascript for now...

Thanks people for your quick and good answers! Was very helpful :-)

Comment: ... btw, why I am _not_ using a button now: even without action the image will indicate the state of the application, which enables me to  tell myself that it is of course informational as well as action ;) Cheating myself, obviously, slightly, but oh well...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Short Answer

Use an `<img>` - not a button or an anchor or an input - as the rest suggest that the element is interactive, *even without JavaScript*.

### Long Answer

> clicking on the image is supposed to call an action (via javascript, but that's not the point).

I disagree; that *is* the point :)

Because the clicking activates JS-only features, your image should only be available in a JS environment.

As such the proper way is to insert it with JavaScript; while an HTML document should be semantically correct, a DOM structure doesn't really need to be semantically correct, so which element you use becomes irrelevant.

### The Wrong Way

```
<div>
    Click on the image to do something: <a href="javascript:wtv()" style="background-image:url(...)">&nbsp;</a>
</div>
<div>
    Click on the image to do something: <input type="image" onclick="wtv()" src="..." />
</div>
<div>
   Click on the image to do something: <img onclick="wtv()" src="..." />
</div>
<div>
    Click on the image to do something: <button onclick="wtv()"><img onclick="wtv()" src="..." /></button>
</div>
```

These are all wrong because a user who doesn't have JavaScript sees these items and can't use them.

Of all of these, I'd say the `<img>` is the lesser evil, as it doesn't suggest an interactive element. The greatest evil is using the `<a>` as an anchor should be a hyperlink to another document, and you should never, *ever* use the `javascript:` protocol.

You'll still have the same problem when you add the JavaScript event handlers externally:

```
/* external .js file */
document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = wtv;

<!-- HTML document -->
<div id="myButtonParent">
    Click on the image to do something: <a id="myButton" href="#" style="background-image:url(...)">&nbsp;</a>
</div>
```

As, again, you still have the (non-functioning) hyperlink available to those users who don't have JavaScript.

### Instead

Instead, insert the whole damn thing using DOM scripting! I'm going to use an `<img>` with an `onclick` event:

```
/* external .js file */
window.onload = function() {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "...";
    img.onclick = wtv;
    img.style.cursor = "pointer"; // so the mouse turns into a finger,
                                  // like on a hyperlink
                                  // Note: instead assign a class attribute and put this in an external CSS file...
    document.getElementById("myButtonParent").appendChild(img);
}
```

Comment: While I agree with most of what you've said, I think dynamically creating any content that a user would interact with and result in some action might be going a bit far. Now if he needs to support a client without scripting then yes I would consider this. I'm just glad I've never worked on a web project which had to support this user minority.

Comment: Hey great! Did not only give me examples on how not to do it, but also gave me a headstart on how to do DOM scripting... Great as an example to do further learning :)

But as said above, I have the good excuse that for my case the app is inhouse so I can tell people to please enable js ;)

Comment: @Josh - I interpret "proper" as meaning "theoretically ideal" ;)

Comment: I take the view of Proper being what is the best way to do something today and takes into account what is theoretically ideal but also what is practical and manageable, and easy to read and understand. I think in this case dynamically building the image tag adds a lot of additional complexity (not so bad with one element but if he had 5,10 or 20 images it could get out of hand quickly).  To each his own:-0)

Comment: ... how 'bout we meet halfway at "he totally drop that and use jQuery." ? ;) But I agree that the more important point is to use an `<image />` rather than to do it all in JS.

Answer (score 2):

You could add an onclick event for the image:

```
<img id='image1' onclick="javascript:DoSomething()"...
```

or add it via jquery:

```
$("#image1").click(
function() {
     DoSomething();
  });
```

I don't think you should use an anchor tag here. Anchoring is for navigating not doing things. Not to mention if you use the beforeunload events, they will get fired if you use an anchor.

While the div works it doesn't add anything semantically to the page. You are not defining a distinct chunk of the page you need to make an image clickable.

I don't use a button control enough to talk about that as an option.

Comment: Thanks for the reasoning for why not to use an anchor or div! It is all more clear to me now, having some reasoning...

Answer (score -3):

Do not quite understand what you want to achieve. But have you tried image input?

```
<input type="image" src="image source">
```

It will do an operation similar to form submit.